# How to implement http video streaming (HLS)

Tags: http, http-live-streaming

I want to implement a simple server (C++) that generates (captures) video stream and sends it to a browser.
The question is: how should the server interact with a browser ?
I am considering a "HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)" technology as the simplest, because I have mastered of network/http interaction is work.

If I understood correctly:

1. the server should split video and prepare M3U8 file that describes the sequence of chunks - small video files,
   The following steps is not quite clear for me.
2. the browser send GET request (?) to receive M3U8, gets a list of the chunks,
3. the browser play downloaded chunks,
4. the next step is unclear - in stream (live) video is continuing - how the browser can know - which names of the next chunks ?

I see I have lost logic here …

How to force the browser to get video chunks continuously ? 
Maybe I am wrong about something above ? Could you explain me the basic steps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am considering a "HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)" technology as the simplest, because I have mastered of network/http interaction is work.

It definitely isn't the simplest, in most cases.  Handling a simple HTTP request and streaming a continuous stream is far easier.  And then, the client side is just a `<video>` element.

> 2. the browser send GET request (?) to receive M3U8, gets a list of the chunks,

Correct.

> 4. the next step is unclear - in stream (live) video is continuing - how the browser can know - which names of the next chunks ?

It downloads a fresh copy of the M3U8 playlist to figure out what's next.

> How to force the browser to get video chunks continuously ?

HLS clients know to refresh the playlist.  It's also possible to build a client to just "know" what segments will be next.  For instance, if you had a sequential list, there's no reason for the client to keep requesting the playlist over and over again.

Sequential playlists have some gotchas though, around negative caching.  If you use a CDN, turn off caching for any non-ok response because someone might hit your segment URLs before they are ready, causing your CDN to assume they will never exist.

Comment: Brad, as regards of your comment: "Handling a simple HTTP request and streaming a continuous stream is far easier.". But I have had in mind exactly it. May be I get confused in terminology, but the steps I described - is not HLS ?

Comment: Brad, you said: "It downloads a fresh copy of the M3U8 playlist to figure out what's next.". Does in mean the browser downloads "m3u8" with the _same_ name many times ?

Comment: @Tobic That's correct.